# Electronic device that can pick up on audible alarms in house, to be used to trigger other action?

Tags: audio, detector

I have done some searching for products that can do this but am having a hard time finding anything. I have a number of different alarms in my house, such as smoke alarm, leak detection alarms, carbon monoxide, etc. They are all basic, low-tech audible alarms. I'm not able to invest in a bunch of new alarms that have SMS / phone calling capability. I figured there must be some electronic device that can pickup on audible alarms and then be able to trigger an action, this way I could have one of these devices that would pickup any of the alarms, as they would all be within a certain audio frequency. Any info is appreciated. Ideally I'm hoping to get a device that can either make a phone call or send an SMS when something occurs, however, I'm willing to take that part on as a project (I'm a software developer so interested to learn a bit more about electronics). Thanks for any info.

Comment: Do these alarms have LED as well? these LED would be much easier to detect.

Comment: The Alertme.com system certainly used to have smoke detector audio detectors; not sure whether they're still selling those.

Comment: @martinm, I believe so, I will check, what would I use to detect the LED? I would need a sensor next to each alarm then I suppose.

Comment: Then you can use a simple photo-transistor to detect if the LED is lit on not. You will need one photo-transistor per LED you want to monitor, for instance SFH 310-2/3 ($0.60 per unit). You can use a Rasberry PI, an Arduino for interfacing. You can also have a look that blog article which shows how to interface an alarm with such photo-transistors and a Yocto-Knob ***beware, I do work for that Yoctopuce company***  http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/connecting-that-which-cannot-be-connected

Comment: @martinm Thanks, this is great info, I will definitely be looking into this more!

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for the audio frequency sensor: http://www.convict.lu/Jeunes/Spielberg/Spielberg.htm

The issue is that you do not want to activate it from other sounds and have to just detect a particular sound frequency.The above sensor/circuit can be used with a micro like an arduino or anything you are comfortable with a GSM Module(which will be the expensivev part) to send SMS.